# Must I say to users if I using library

Tags: android, charts, shared-libraries

I want to use bar chart in my app. I search a lot of website and I see MpChart library again and again. If I used this library must I mention this library. I mean must I write under my chart (Thanks to MpChart).
I am new in android programing. What is the mean of lisance. If a library have a lisance what is mean of this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a legal question not a programming one.  Consult a lawyer.

Comment: Thanks for your warning. But the legal problems block me. I can't make my problem because of this reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out they are using [Apache License](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0) as stated in their [mpchart repo](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). You can read the entire license term [here](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0). I think it's okay **not** to write "*thanks to mpchart*" based on my understanding from the license term.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I read a lot of web site. If I understand right I can use bar chart. I don't have to write thank you Apache. Apache lisance's mean is I can't sue about Apache code. And maybe I can't get lisance of my program.

Comment: Edit: I can get lisance of my program. But I must add Apache lisance into my program also.